# How can I isolate one candle?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to make a drawing tool that draws a horizontal ray at the midpoint of a chosen candle.  I want to be able to left click and highlight a candle and apply the drawing tool to the candle. The problem is, I cannot isolate a single candle.  Every time I left-click on the candle all the candles are selected.  Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

I have a script that measures the high and low of a candle and measures the mid-point and then draw a horizontal ray from the midpoint of the current candle.  It does it for every new candle but it is not what I want.  I want to only apply it to certain candles I choose.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With pinescript you can't get user input from the chart.

Comment: @theblockof ok, can you accept the answer to close it ?